# z-index stacking issue with Chrome and Google Maps

Tags: css, google-maps, google-chrome, z-index

I'm working on the beta of a website that has a "docking" header. When the visitor scrolls down the page the header locks in place and the page content slides under the header.

This works fine on content pages like this: http://www.aride.org.nz/longest-day/how-to-do-the-longest-day-ride/

But doesn't work on pages which have Google Maps on them like this: http://www.aride.org.nz/longest-day/2013/

You may need to reduce your viewport size so you can scroll the page down far enough.

This seems to only happen on Chrome. It works as expected on Safari 5, Firefox 23, Opera 15 and even (ugh) Internet Explorer 9.

Looking at the page in Chrome using Web Developer shows all of the correct stack levels with the z-index for the main content set at 1 - compared to 99/999/9999 for the header and navigation.

Any ideas would be appreciated - I've hit a wall at my end.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am running into a similar problem!!

Comment: @user2559519 - unfortunately not. It gradually sucked my will to live away so I came up with a half-arsed work around and left it at that.

Comment: Oh. What was the workaround? I'm in the same position. No one seems to know what's wrong. For me it happens with any iframe/embed with a docked header.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

I believe having your `#header-container` element remain fixed, rather than the child `header` element itself, will fix your problem. Something to do with [stacking contexts](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/), which I won't pretend to fully understand.

**Explanation:**

Your layout is breaking due to Google's use of 3d transforms in Maps. [Here's a related question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472802/css-z-index-lost-after-webkit-transform-translate3d)

**tl;dr:**

3d transforms screw up the browsers ability to determine stacking order on affected elements.

Comment: Thank you Shawn. I'm still trying to work out how to disable the 3D aspect of Google Maps on embed.

Comment: Ah - use the static maps API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#quick_example