# Disappearing element with fullPage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, fullpage.js

I'm trying to get the fullPage.js (https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js) on my site but when I slide down one and slide back up, the `div` on the `video` element is like disappearing and not sliding back with the video nicely, just pop, and appears. As far as I see it works well in Firefox.

Demo: http://beta.brainfunkers.co

Any ideas on this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not seeing any issues in either firefox or chrome, or am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: @JeremyC. Possibly. When you scroll one down the video and the BF logo slides out nicely. When you scroll back up, the video slides back but the logo is not sliding, just appearing once the slide is complete.

Comment: you mean the one div with the image and the "what we do" and the other one that contains text that says "pillow fight" right?

Answer (score 1):

That's [a webkit bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472802/css-z-index-lost-after-webkit-transform-translate3d) as you can see [here](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=61824), so the problem its in Chrome.

Anyway, to solve it add the following style for your logo:

```
.topImage .topImageContainer .bfLogo{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```