# Maintaining z-index order after rotated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my div structure

```
<div id="outer">
   <div class="inner">
      <div>
         <div class="item"></div>   
      </div>
        <div class="itemBelow">
            <div class="innerBelow"></div>
        </div> 
   </div>
</div>

#outer{ /*parent and children - rotateable*/
  top:10px;
  width:220px;
  height:50px;
  position: absolute;
  background:blue;
}
.inner{
  top:35px;
  width:200px;
  height:75px;
  position: relative;
  background:green;
}
.item{
  top:60px;
  width:180px;
  height:100px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 4; /*to be top most div*/
  display: block;
  background:red;
}
.itemBelow{
  top:160px;
  width:160px;
  height:120px;
  position: relative;
  background:pink;
}
.innerBelow{
  top: 105px;
  width:140px;
  height:140px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1; /*to be lowest div*/
  background:lime;
}
```

I'm trying to rotate `#outer` div and its children.

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $('.outer').css({
        '-webkit-transform': 'rotateZ(45deg)',
        '-msTransform': 'rotateZ(45deg)',
        'transform': 'rotateZ(45deg)',
    });
});
```

But how can I maintain the z-index order after rotation? I expect the output to remain in the below z-index order before and after `#outer` is rotated.

```
item //top div
stillObj //second highest div
innerBelow //lowest div
```

I have created a mockup. See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NathaliaZeed/g0mfk8cq/2/)

I have googled and come across many post like [z-index and transform](http://katydecorah.com/code/z-index-and-transform/), [transform-translate3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472802/css-z-index-lost-after-webkit-transform-translate3d). But I'm unable to make this work.

Comment: @Harry. Thanks. Yes you are correct. I did post it few hours back but I felt I haven't added enough details in it for a answer. So I decided to remove it and create a fiddle and post more info in a fresh post.

Comment: @Harry No worries mate. I hope I'm not voilation any rules here and hopefully this question has enough info to understand my question better.

Comment: I am looking at your fiddle (tried it in Safari, Chrome and Firefox) - when I click the `button`, nothing happens. What is the intended behavior for it?

Comment: There are some problems in your fiddle please try to fix them firstly.

Comment: @Quoid: Thanks. `#outer` should rotate maintaining its z-indexes.

Comment: @Becky can you correct your fiddle, and then update your question? It's not functioning/displaying the issue you've described

Comment: @Quoid: Thanks. I've updated my post. https://jsfiddle.net/NathaliaZeed/g0mfk8cq/2/

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Thanks. I've updated my post. https://jsfiddle.net/NathaliaZeed/g0mfk8cq/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the css property [`transform-style`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-style.asp) to keep your 'stacking order' or `z-index` when using css3 3d transforms.

You can see in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g0mfk8cq/6/), even when transformed, the element (`.item`) retained it's `z-index` value relative to the `.stillObj`.

You have to apply `transform-style` to *both* elements that need to retain their `z-index` and will also be 'interacting' with a 3d `transform`.

Here is an example of some of the *types* of structuring/class changes you'd have to make to your specific example in orderto keep the `z-index` values sticking: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wfemffv0/).

It seems as if you need to put `preserve-3d` on the elements themselves (that will have a 3d `transform`), not their parents in order to preserve the stacking order.

```js
$('#btn').click(function(){
 $('.item').toggleClass('rotate');
});
```

```css
.stillObj{
    height: 450px;
    width: 30px;
    background: #666;
    z-index:2;/*to be second height div*/
    position: relative;
}
#outer{ /*parent and children - rotateable*/
  top:10px;
  width:220px;
  height:50px;
  position: absolute;
  background:blue;
}
.inner{
  top:35px;
  width:200px;
  height:75px;
  position: relative;
  background:green;
}
.item{
  top:60px;
  width:180px;
  height:100px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 4; /*to be top most div*/
  display: block;
  background:red;
}
.itemBelow{
  top:160px;
  width:160px;
  height:120px;
  position: relative;
  background:pink;
}
.innerBelow{
  top: 105px;
  width:140px;
  height:140px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1; /*to be lowest div*/
  background:lime;
}
#btn{
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    height: 60px;
}

.rotate {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(15deg);
        transform: rotateZ(15deg);
}

.item, .stillObj {
     -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="btn">Click</button>

<div class="stillObj"></div>

<div id="outer">
   <div class="inner">
      <div>
         <div class="item"></div>   
      </div>
        <div class="itemBelow">
            <div class="innerBelow"></div>
        </div> 
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Quold. I checked in chrome but only `#item` (red square) is rotating? I'm looking for a way to rotate `#outer` and its children to rotate simultaneously while maintaining their stacking order.

Comment: Right, I slimmed down the code to demonstrate how the solution works.  It seems the elements with `z-index` are the ones that need the `preserve-3d` value. So you will have to adjust your code in order preserve your stacking order. It's very easy to implement into your current structure/code.

Comment: @Becky here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/wfemffv0/) of how you could/should alter your classes/structure but maintain the same type of effect - hope this helps a bit more

Comment: Just one more thing please. Other than `-webkit-` which other once should I use in my css?

Comment: @Becky it depends on the browser you want to support - I [use this website](http://shouldiprefix.com) a lot when to figure out my prefixes. I think `-ms` should be used with `transform` if you want IE 9 support - [This is also a great website for prefixes](http://pleeease.io/play/)