# CSS transform with parent transform does not work on iOS Safari

Tags: html, css, sass

I created a mockup of the situation because I wasn't able to create a testable version so easily. But to get the gist:

```css
@keyframes mainFadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-3rem);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

// If I use this, without the transform, then everything works.
// 
// @keyframes mainFadeIn {
//   0% {
//     opacity: 0;
//   }
// 
//   100% {
//     opacity: 1;
//   }
// }

.main {
  animation-name: mainFadeIn;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 16rem;
  padding: 3rem;
}

.card {
  transition: transform 500ms;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  perspective: 200px; // Ignore
  margin: auto;
  width: 30rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background-color: lightblue;
  
  &.flipped {
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  }
}

.front,
.back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.back {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="back"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hopefully this is enough to know where the issue is.

CodePen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/owvqQP/

**EDIT**
Well. It's probably this thing: [css z-index lost after webkit transform translate3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472802/css-z-index-lost-after-webkit-transform-translate3d)

But I still can't get it to work. The only solution would be to use `position: relative;` and `top: 0;` and `top: -3rem;` for the animations..

Comment: what is the version of your ios safari?

Comment: iOS 9.2.1 ist the OS version.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you forgot `-webkit-` prefix. Also recommend using translate3d for hardware acceleration. Try this way:

```
@-webkit-keyframes mainFadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -3rem, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -3rem, 0);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes mainFadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -3rem, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -3rem, 0);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

.main {
  -webkit-animation-name: mainFadeIn;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-name: mainFadeIn;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 16rem;
  padding: 3rem;
}

.card {
  transition: -webkit-transform 500ms;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 500ms;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-perspective: 200px; // Ignore
  perspective: 200px; // Ignore
  margin: auto;
  width: 30rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background-color: lightblue;

  &.flipped {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  }
}

.front,
.back {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
```